# PDF Exported Document Formatting

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, export-to-pdf

I am downloading data in Pdf form, but my document is not grid look

[image]

Below is the code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ClientRecord.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
GridView1.Style.Add("border", "solid 2px blue");
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Can anybody help me with that, plz?

Comment: Debug issue in steps.  You may have multiple issues.  First verify the pdf in response is good.  Check the byte count (to make sure it is the same as original file) and save the received file so you can make sure it a good by opening.   Then verify the code for opening the pdf in c# is good.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but my code is working fine, but i am unable to style my document, i have attached a screenshot of my document you can see. i want something like table styling or row color...something like that.. Thanks

Comment: The `HTMLWorker` class is deprecated (has been so for many many years) because it supports only very few html tags and attributes. For better styling of html-to-pdf conversions with itext, use the `XMLWorker` or even better the itext 7 pdfHtml component.